# Webapp update shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I feel silly asking this...

I am not an expert on shell scripting, but I am finally in enough of a sysadmin role that I want to do this correctly.

I have a production server that hosts a webapp.  Here is my routine.
1 - ssh to server
2 - cd django_src/django_apps/team_proj
3 - svn update
4 - sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
5 - logout

I want to create a shell script for steps 2,3,4.

I can do this, but it will be a very plain and simple bash script simply containing the actual commands I type at the command line.

My question:  What is the *best* way to script this kind of repetitive procedure in bash (Linux, Ubuntu) for a remote server?

Thanks!

Comment: This *is* a programming question, but if your'e a sysadmin you might want to submit more questions like this to ServerFault instead of StackOverflow.

Comment: How have I missed that site!  Thanks for the pointer.  I'm not really a sysadmin, I just do a bit of it as a necessity like many programmers.

Answer (score 4):

The best way is simply as you suggest. Some things you should do for your script would be:

- put `set -e` at the top of the script (after the shebang). This will cause your script to stop if any of the commands fail. So if it cannot cd to the directory, it will not run `svn update` or restart apache. You can do this programmatically by putting `|| exit 0` after each command, but if that's all you're doing, you may as well use `set -e`
- Use full paths in your script. Do not assume the directory that the script is run from. In this specific case, the `cd` command has a relative path. Use a full (absolute) path, or use an environment variable like $HOME.
- You may want to set up sudo so that it can run the command without asking for a password. This makes your script non-interactive which means it can be run in the background and from cron jobs and such.

As time goes by, you may add features and take command line arguments to parameterise the script. But don't bother doing this up front. Just evolve your scripts as you need.

Comment: how do you setup sudo so it doesn't requests a password?

Comment: Don't forget to create a public/private key for ssh so you can run ssh from an automated script.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong with a simple bash script simply containing the actual commands you type at the command line. Don't make it more complicated than necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I'd setup a cron job doing that automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using python, check out [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/0.9.0/) - you can use it to automate these kind of tasks. First install fabric:

```
$ sudo easy_install fabric
```

then write your fabric script:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from fabric.api import *

def svnupdate():
    with cd('django_src/django_apps/team_proj'):
        run('svn update')
        sudo('/etc/init.d/apache2 restart')
```

Save as `fabfile.py`, then run using the `fab` command:

```
$ fab -H hostname svnupdate
```

Tell me that's not cool! :-)

Comment: Who said the question asker was using Python ?

Comment: @gareth_bowles: he's deploying django app from internal svn - it might be safe to assume he knows at least a little bit of python ;)

Comment: Good question! He's using django, which is a python framework for web development (a little like Ruby on Rails, but in python)

Comment: Oh I know python ;)  Do I need to install anything on the server to support fabric?

Comment: Hi Art - dependencies are documented at http://docs.fabfile.org/0.9.0/installation.html - you need Python 2.5 or newer, Setuptools and PyCrypto. On every system I've used fabric on these dependencies have already been installed and fabric "just works". Check out the installation link for more info and pointers for where to find the dependencies if you don't already have them installed.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with the shell (bash,ksh,zsh + ssh + tools), or programming languages such as Python,Perl(Ruby or PHP or Java) etc, basically a language that supports SSH protocol and operating system functions. The "best" one is the one that you are more comfortable and have knowledge in. If you are doing sysadmin, the shell is the closest thing you can use. Then after you have done your script, you can use the crontab (cron) , or the at command to schedule your task. check their man page for more information

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do the above using bash/Bourne etc.

However I would take the time and effort to learn Perl (or some similarly powerful scripting language). Why ?

1. the language constructs are much more powerful
2. there are no end of libraries to interface to the systems/features you want to script
3. because of the library support, you won't have to spawn off different commands to achieve what you want (possibly valuable on a loaded system)
4. you can decompose frequently-used scripts into your own libraries for later use

I choose Perl particularly because it's been designed (perhaps *designed* is too strong a word for Perl) for these sort of tasks. However you may want to check out Ruby/Python or other suggestions from SO contributers.

Answer (score 1):

For the basic steps look at camh's answer. If you plan to run the script via cron, then implement some simple logging, e.g. by appending start time of each command with exit code to a textfile which you can later analyze for failures of the script.

Answer (score 1):

**Expect -- scripting interactive applications**

> Expect is a tool for automating interactive applications such as telnet, ftp, passwd, fsck, rlogin, tip, etc.... Expect can make easy all sorts of tasks that are prohibitively difficult with anything else. You will find that Expect is an absolutely invaluable tool - using it, you will be able to automate tasks that you've never even thought of before - and you'll be able to do this automation quickly and easily.

http://expect.nist.gov

bonus: Your tax dollars at work!

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do something like this...

project_update.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# $1 - user@host
# $2 - project directory

[[ -z $1 || -z $2 ]] && { echo "usage: $(basename $0) user@host project_dir"; exit 1; }

declare host=$1 proj_dir=$2

ssh $host "cd $proj_dir;svn update;sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart" && echo "Success"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another tip - you should not give users access to some application in an unknown state. `svn up` might break during the update, users might see a page that's half-new half-old, etc. If you're deploying the whole application at once, I'd suggest doing `svn export` instead to a new directory and then either `mv current old ; mv new current`, or even keeping `current` as a link to the directory you're using now. Still not perfect and not blocking every possible race condition, but it definitely takes less time than `svn up` on the live copy.